# Numerical paging for GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custompaging

I am using a GridView to display data from database. Using ASP.Net 4.0 with C#. The GV is given DataTable as its data source. I need to display numerical paging to this grid where the user can see Next and Previous buttons along with "page number links" like

<< Prev 1 2 3 ... Next >>

on top right section of the grid. Is there any way to do this using custom paging or any built in feature of GV? What kind of event I need to handle for the page number clicks? Can anybody please point me to right direction or code snippet?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

```
 `allowpaging="true"` in gridview
```

then write you `pagersettings`  as

```
<pagersettings mode="NumericFirstLast"
            firstpagetext="First"
            lastpagetext="Last"
            pagebuttoncount="5"  
            position="Bottom"/>
```

[you can see detail here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.mode.aspx)

(Optional) on server side

place your page change logic in `PageIndexChanged`

Answer (score 1):

1. Set AllowPaging property to true.
2. Set GridView.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast
3. Set  position="Top" and add the following to markup

   ```
   <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
   ```
4. Attach to the PageIndexChanged event to handle page numeric clicks

[Here is good example.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Aug/18/GridView-and-Paging-Alignment)

You can find more details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx